# Cordova Platform Add Error - Version Cannot be longer than 256 Characters

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have installed IONIC and Cordova on my new laptop. Installed JAVA, Android etc.
When i try to add platform android, i get errors for all 4 plugins.
Error message is: 
    **TypeError: version is longer than 256 characters**

```
ionic cordova build android
[INFO] Enabling Cordova integration.
> ionic config set integrations.cordova {} --json --force
[OK] integrations.cordova set to {} in .\ionic.config.json!
> cordova platform add android --save
в Running command - failed!
[ERROR] Exception: Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@~6.2.2

    Adding android project...
    Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
            Path: platforms\android
            Package: io.ionic.starter
            Name: MyApp
            Activity: MainActivity
            Android target: android-25
    Subproject Path: CordovaLib
    Android project created with cordova-android@6.2.3
    Discovered plugin "cordova-plugin-console" in config.xml. Adding it to the project
    Installing "cordova-plugin-console" for android
    Failed to install 'cordova-plugin-console': TypeError: version is longer than 256 characters
         at new SemVer (C:\Users\hillesc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\semver\semver.js:283:11)
         at compare (C:\Users\hillesc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\semver\semver.js:566:10)
         at Function.gte (C:\Users\hillesc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\semver\semver.js:615:10)
         at C:\Users\hillesc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\install.js:629:24
         at _fulfilled (C:\app3\todo\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:854:54)
         at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\app3\todo\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:883:30)
         at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\app3\todo\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:816:13)
         at C:\app3\todo\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:624:44
         at runSingle (C:\app3\todo\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
         at flush (C:\app3\todo\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
    Failed to restore plugin "cordova-plugin-console" from config.xml. You might need to try adding it again. Error: TypeError: version is longer than 256 characters

    Running command: "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\app3\todo\hooks\after_prepare\010_add_platform_class.js C:\app3\todo
    add to body class: platform-android
    --save flag or autosave detected
    Saving android@~6.2.3 into config.xml file ...
```

ionic info

```
cli packages: (C:\Users\hillesc\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2
```

global packages:

```
Cordova CLI : 7.0.1
```

local packages:

```
Cordova Platforms : android C:\app3\todo>set cihdrive=c: C:\app3\todo>set cihdir=c:\cih C:\app3\todo>set servdir=c:\cih\service C:\app3\todo>path C:\Users\hillesc\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\local\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Users\hillesc\bin;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\xTools;C:\windows\SYSTEM32;C:\windows;C:\windows\SYSTEM32\WBEM;C:\windows\SYSTEM32\WINDOWSPOWERSHELL\V1.0;C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\INTEL\SERVICES\IPT;C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\COMMON FILES\ULEAD SYSTEMS\MPEG;C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software;C:\Program Files\ThinkPad\Bluetooth Software\syswow64;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET\ASP.NET Web Pages\v1.0;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Intuit\QBPOSSDKRuntime;C:\Program Files (x86)\Hyland\Web ActiveX;C:\Program Files\Microsoft System Center 2012 R2\Service Manager;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon;C:\Users\hillesc\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin;C:\Users\hillesc\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools;C:\Users\hillesc\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\core_perl;c:\cih\util 6.2.3
Ionic Framework   : ionic1 1.3.3
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.0.2
Node              : v6.11.2
npm               : 3.10.10
OS                : Windows 7
```

Comment: there seems to be some problem with your cordova platforms list. It should generally be like android, ios, browser etc.. But is list some irrelevant paths in your case, Try checking out your environmental variable settings for ANDROID_HOME

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for that comment Gandhi.  Yes I found the problem, and it may help 1 person out of millions:  I had a registry entry in HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor that automatically runs a job (a.bat, kind of like the old "autoexec.bat") that has the exact wierd SET commands in it.

Somehow the fact that this was running every time a command prompt opened, corrupted my platforms.

Once I took that out, everything looks normal now in the "platforms" part of the "ionic info" command.  Thanks! (My colleague posted this question for me so I can't give points sorry).